# Loop for into while

Tags: java, sql

I have a sql query to select data integer

I want do a test about this data that I test data in column with number 10

If I have 10 in column so pass to 10--

I do loop for into while

The result is correct but it's repeated many times

This is my code

```
int vl=10;
boolean found = false;
try {
    if (jComboBox6.getSelectedIndex()>-1){
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+getdb(), "", "");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT VLAN FROM tt ");                         
        while(res.next()) {
            for(vl=10;vl>1;vl--) {    
                if(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(1))==vl) {
                    System.out.print(vl);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (!found) {
                    System.out.print("NO");
                    //found = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    res.close();
}
conn.close();            
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Etat_lieu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: So... if the result is correct, what is the problem?

Comment: he repeat the NO many times

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.print("NO")`

this line will be printed every time there is no match in the for loop.

Comment: Yes that's and the data that not exist in column just 10 so it must just be printed 10 times not many times

Comment: @jack : You have a outer while loop for the no. of results. If there are 10 results and there is no match in the for loop , you will have 100 "NO" printed, hope this helps , you can follow the suggestion given by others if you want to skip it.

Comment: okey i understand but how can i resolve that even if i use 'do while' it gives nothing

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Let's simplify the problem.

```
boolean found = false;
while(res.next()) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(res.getString(1));
    if (value == 10) {
        System.out.print(value);
        found = true;
    }
    [..do something else..]
 }
 if(!found) {
    System.out.print("NO");
 }
```

I think it's not worth to put an inner loop for a simple range check.

Comment: here i will not use the boolean ?

Comment: **OUTER:           
while(res.next()) {
    for(vl = 10; vl > 1; vl--) {
        if(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(1))==vl) {
            System.out.print(vl);          
            break OUTER;
        }
    }
    if(found)
        System.out.print("No");
        break OUTER;
}**

Comment: @Jack In your comment you forgot the `{}` from `if(found) { System.out.print("No"); break OUTER;}` - so you jumped off at the first iteration.

Comment: Oh Sorry i try to use the '' for code like you say in comment formatting

Comment: I realized what you're trying to resolve and how. The previous code would not work, but this one will.

Comment: it gives nothing i don't know why

Comment: i try this last but it gives nothing @GaborSch

Comment: That must be some different error then, maybe something with your SQL. Try logging or debugging.

Comment: it gives one NO it's correct or ?? because the 10 numbers not exists in column

Comment: i must use the loop because i want use the data that not exists in table in another instructions so i must use look even if this code works

Comment: This version checks only `10`

Comment: that's what i do : `for(int vl=20;vl>1;vl--) {
while(res.next())
                {
                    boolean found = false;
                   if(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(1))==vl)
                   {
                       System.out.print("exist"+vl);
                       found = true;
                       break;
                   }
                   else if (!found){
                         System.out.print("NO"+vl);
                       break;`

Comment: I'm sorry, I give up. I cannot teach you programming, logical thinking, etc. And no, I won't solve your problem, you have to do it. If you have a *specific* question, we can help in that. But you are not showing even a minimal understanding of the problem.

Comment: Good luck with experimenting, that's the way you learn things. :)

Comment: it's 2 weeks that i am working on that and i study networking systems but i have project with java so it's the first time that i work with java for that i ask some questions that you find so easy but for me it's difficult to resolve